# Returning an array of images from a database using HTTP handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, handler

I have written a handler that returns me one imaage from the database which display. Nw i want to an array of iamges which are related to a specific image. Like If image " A is related to image "B","C" and "D" , I want A,B,C, and D images to be returned by the http handler. So that i can show the images on the web page. How do I return an array of images or list of images?

here is my handler code.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="DisplayImg" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class DisplayImg : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string theID;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            theID = context.Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Stream strm = DisplayImage(theID);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);

        while (byteSeq > 0)
        {
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
            byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
        }
    }

    public Stream DisplayImage(string theID)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SERVER"].ConnectionString.ToString());
        string sql = "SELECT Server_image_icon FROM tbl_ServerMaster WHERE server_Code = @ID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", theID);
        connection.Open();
        object theImg = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        try
        {
            return new MemoryStream((byte[])theImg);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited your question because your capslock key appears to be stuck.

Comment: @Ankur:
How are images related?

Comment: @Razort4x my images can be 1 to many related or 1 to 1 related. I am saving image mappings in DB. SO when a particular images is selected, in DB i am cheking for the images that are related or mapped to the selected image and I want to show all these images.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in a single httphandler, since you are returning a stream of bytes. Here is how you might do it in two steps:

1) write a new httphandler which returns a list of image URLs that are related.

2) make the above URLs point to your DisplayImg handler.

The browser will render your first handler's result and then it will fetch each image using your second handler (DisplayImg).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you elaborate the solution a bit more.I am new to using the handlers.